# compress very large resolution image file using Imagemagick

Tags: image, compression, imagemagick, mogrify

I have some scanned images of resolution 20400x28056. I want them to be compressed using imagemagick. I tried 
`convert ToBeCompressed.jpeg -quality 70 output.jpeg` but this command is making my laptop crashed. I think it is not able to handle such large resolution. Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things to check... your image corresponds to around 1.6GB of raw data so you may find you need to be running a 64-bit environment, rather than 32-bit. If you are on Windows, you may need to be running on an NTFS filesystem rather than FAT because FAT filesystems, though they can be up to 130GB in size, cannot support individual files larger than 2GB, or maybe 4GB if you are lucky.

Finally, could you consider *resizing* the image rather than reducing its quality, if you resize it *on-the-fly* as you read it in, you may do better since it is less resource-intensive. So, say you decided you could accept an image half the length on each side (1/4 of the original area)

```
convert input.jpg[50%x50%] -quality 70 output.jpg
```

Depending on what you actually want to do with the image afterwards, you could use ImageMagick's `stream` utility to split the image into chunks. It reads the image a row at a time so it only uses very little memory. So, to get the two halves of the image into a raw format, you could do

```
stream  -extract 20400x14028+0+0     ToBeCompressed.jpg tophalf.rgb
stream  -extract 20400x14028+0+14028 ToBeCompressed.jpg bottomhalf.rgb
```

Then, if you want to convert those raw RGB files to JPG, you can do

```
convert -depth 8 -size 20400x14028 tophalf.rgb tophalf.jpg
```

Another avenue you could pursue might be `vips`, which is described [here](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/).

So, if your image is called `BigBoy.jpg` you could do this to set the quality to 60, for example:

```
vips jpegsave BigBoy.jpg BB60.jpg --Q=60
```

which results in this on my system

```
ls -l Bi* BB60.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  270283175 19 Mar 14:17 BB60.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  997198223 19 Mar 14:07 BigBoy.jpg
```

Comment: Yes that vips thing solved my issue thank you so much, but again i have one little problem i was going through the vips documentation and i found that it also supports Webp but i am not able to figure what would be the right command to convert jpeg to webp.

Comment: webp only supports images up to 16,000 x 16,000,  so I don't think it'll be useful for you. The syntax is `vips webpsave a.jpg x.webp` if you want to try it.